# laravel 4 returns error in file upload

Tags: php, image, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

My problem is I am getting upload error when I try to upload a big image. (Greater than 2MB).

My upload size limit in php.ini is 40MB and I still get the following error:

```
 development.ERROR: exception 'Exception' with message Serialization of   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php:212
 Stack trace:
 #0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php(212): serialize(Array)
 #1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(126): Illuminate\Session\Store->save()
 #2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(79): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->closeSession(Object(Illuminate\Session\Store))
 #3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
 #4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
 #5 /var/www/laravel/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
 #6 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(606): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
 #7 /var/www/laravel/public/index.php(61): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
 #8 {main} [] []
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: Jump to terminal `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session`
If still the same try `777`

Comment: I tried but still get the same error.

Comment: Check this link http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to upload a file ? With native laravel upload functions of with bundle ? Permissions can be just one of the problems.

Comment: I am using only native upload.